# Check if a coupon is applied to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I need to find a way to check if a coupon is applied to WooCommerce checkout, if so I would like to do something.  I have tried searching around for this and cannot find a solution.

Here is a slimmed down version of what I am trying:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon( ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_id = '12345';
        
        if( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons === $coupon_id ) {
        echo 'YAY it works';
    }
}
```

So is this not the right way to check if the coupon exists in cart? `if( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons === $coupon_id )`

Comment: What is the result of your test?

Comment: Well in this example if the coupon "12345" is applied to cart then it will echo the "Yay it works".  What I really plan on doing is adding a free product to cart if the coupon is applied, I have everything down except checking to see if my coupon is applied.

Comment: Does your test actually echo 'YAY it works'?

Comment: It will once I can test it against the coupon_id, I have no way of checking the applied coupons to see if coupon '12345' is applied to cart or not..  The above code will work if I remove the === $coupon_id, but it works for all coupons applied and not my specific coupon

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From your example, something like this might work. This is untested, but should give you a step in the right direction:

```
add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'apply_product_on_coupon');
function apply_product_on_coupon( ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $coupon_id = '12345';
    $free_product_id = 54321;

    if(in_array($coupon_id, $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons())){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($free_product_id, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the documentation on the [Cart Class](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_to_cart)

Comment: If anyone is interested, WC_Cart::get_applied_coupons() returns an array of coupon code strings, this is not clear in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

```
global $woocommerce;
if (!empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons))
{
        //print_r($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons); - keys of coupons here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be an ages issue but an easy solution is to use

```
WC()->cart->applied_coupons
```

This return array lists of applied coupons, you can then use foreach, for or in_array to check applied coupons.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If you know the coupon code but not the coupon post ID, you can use this mash up of [realmag777's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275299/2073738) and [maiorano84's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101317/2073738).

```
function CheckCouponIsApplied($cpn_code)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $lowercasecouponcode = strtolower($cpn_code); //ENSURE LOWERCASE TO MATCH WOOCOMMERCE NORMALIZATION
    return in_array($lowercasecouponcode, $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons);
}
```